# Default launcher on Android TV via ADB problem

Tags: adb, launcher, android-tv, smart-tv, google-tv

After setting the new GoogleTV Launcher as default via ADB (using the command `adb shell cmd package set-home-activity "com.google.android.apps.tv.launcherx"`) on my Android TV Box, checking the default launcher (always via ADB) using two different methods the shell returns a mismatching result as you can see below, and in practice the manufacturer's own launcher (timvision.launcher) always opens as default. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

```
m393gena_tim:/ $ cmd package resolve-activity -c android.intent.category.HOME
priority=2 preferredOrder=0 match=0x108000 specificIndex=-1 isDefault=true
ActivityInfo:
  name=timvision.launcher.ui.HomeActivity
  packageName=timvision.launcher
  labelRes=0x7f110056 nonLocalizedLabel=null icon=0x7f0801e8 banner=0x7f0801e8
  enabled=true exported=true directBootAware=false
  taskAffinity=timvision.launcher targetActivity=null persistableMode=PERSIST_ROOT_ONLY
  launchMode=3 flags=0x300220 privateFlags=0x0 theme=0x0
  screenOrientation=0 configChanges=0x33 softInputMode=0x0
  lockTaskLaunchMode=LOCK_TASK_LAUNCH_MODE_DEFAULT
  resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_UNRESIZEABLE
  ApplicationInfo:
    name=timvision.launcher.TimLauncher
    packageName=timvision.launcher
    labelRes=0x7f110056 nonLocalizedLabel=null icon=0x7f0e0000 banner=0x0
    className=timvision.launcher.TimLauncher
    processName=timvision.launcher
    taskAffinity=timvision.launcher
    uid=10028 flags=0x28d83ec5 privateFlags=0xc000918 theme=0x7f120013
    requiresSmallestWidthDp=0 compatibleWidthLimitDp=0 largestWidthLimitDp=0
    sourceDir=/data/app/timvision.launcher-_GWEhSuSRLHmn1MVNH9JyQ==/base.apk
    seinfo=default:privapp:targetSdkVersion=29
    seinfoUser=:complete
    dataDir=/data/user/0/timvision.launcher
    deviceProtectedDataDir=/data/user_de/0/timvision.launcher
    credentialProtectedDataDir=/data/user/0/timvision.launcher
    enabled=true minSdkVersion=26 targetSdkVersion=29 versionCode=1216031 targetSandboxVersion=1
    supportsRtl=true
    fullBackupContent=true
    HiddenApiEnforcementPolicy=2
    usesNonSdkApi=false
    allowsPlaybackCapture=true
m393gena_tim:/ $ cmd shortcut get-default-launcher
Launcher: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.tv.launcherx/com.google.android.apps.tv.launcherx.home.HomeActivity}
Success
m393gena_tim:/ $
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to run

```
db shell pm disable-user --user 0 com.google.android.tungsten.setupwraith
```

Wraith seems to hijack the home action.